# Github Pages cannot access files in _app directory

Tags: github, github-pages, sveltekit

I've been using Github Pages to host a demo of a project of mine, however it recently stopped working, throwing 404 errors for all files inside the _app directory, despite the files actually being there. The page is a static build of a SvelteKit app.

Looking online it seems it may related to Jekyll, however I already disabled it creating a `.nojekyll` file.

I already tried re-building pages, but it did not work. Here is a link to the [repo](https://github.com/BearToCode/carta-md/tree/gh-pages) and one to the [site](http://beartocode.me/carta-md/).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the build contained imports that did hold in account the path prefix of the repository(http://[name].me/[repo]). I fixed it by adding this line to my `svelte.config.js`:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build'
        }),
        paths: {
               // Add this line here
            base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/repo-name' : ''
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```